# Rails search and redirect to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, ransack

I am working on Rails 3.2 and I have installed Ransack for search and Kaminari for pagination. Both the gems work absolutely smooth.

I was curious as to how to have the search on the home page and after the user enters the search input, redirect him to another page where all the results are listed.

Something similar to [Zomato](http://www.zomato.com/) search

As of now this is the controller code:

```
def index
  @search = Product.search(params[:q])
  @products = @search.result.page(params[:page]).per(5)  
end
```

And in my view I have:

```
= search_form_for @search do |f| 
  = f.label :locality_cont 
  = f.text_field :locality_cont 
  = f.submit
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to put the correct url:

```
= search_form_for @search, url: my_results_url do |f|
```

Be sure to match 'my_results_url' in routes to a proper action in your desired controller.

Watch [this RailsCast on Ransack](http://railscasts.com/episodes/370-ransack), its pretty awesome